# Haskell longest contiguous series of elements in a list

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I'm new to functional programming and the language haskell. I'm trying to determine the length of the longest contiguous series of elements in a list depending on a predicate function. The function is looks like this:

```
 longestSequence :: (a -> Bool) -> [Int] -> Int
```

When i call it like this:

```
 longestSequence (\x -> x >= 10) [1,44,33,22,2,3,55,66,66,77,88,99]
```

It should give me as solution `6`.

My solution until yet is:

```
longestSequence :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
longestSequence p [] = 0
longestSequence p (x:xs) 
  | (p x) = 1 + (longestSequence p xs)
  | otherwise = longestSequence p xs
```

Any hints or ideas of how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Why should it give you 6, and what is it giving you instead?

Comment: I think I get the spec: it's the length of the longest contiguous series of elements that all satisfy the predicate.

Comment: With my solution i get 9, because i'm counting all items if the predicate is true

Comment: Sorry for the misleading topic of the question. @luqui spec is correct.

Comment: As you just want the length of the longest sequence, not the longest sequence itself, it might help to `map` the predicate across the list, then find the longest sequence of `True`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to factor out smaller sub-problems. For this example the general strategy might be like this:

1. Convert the given list into a `[Bool]` list where an entry is `True` if the corresponding entry satisfies the predicate. That is write a function `(Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> [Bool]`
2. Group consecutive `True` and `False` values. That is write a function `[Bool] -> [[Bool]]`. You might want to look at [`Data.List.group`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group).
3. Filter out the `False` groups: `[[Bool]] -> [[Bool]]`
4. For each of the inner lists count their length. `[[Bool]] -> [Int]`
5. Find the maximum of those lengths: `[Int] -> Int`

Then you just have to compose those functions and you are done. For 1. and 4. you will want to use the function `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. If you already know `map`, just use it. If you don't I would suggest writing that yourself as well.

Some of the type signatures for the functions that I gave are overly specific. Maybe try to generalise them a bit where you can.

Comment: need to filter out the `False` groups, in case one of them is jolly long

Comment: This was very good explanation to solve my problem :) Thank you very much @jpath !

Comment: A Last question to you @jpath: Takes the solution of your explanation linear time -> O(n)?

Comment: @Oni1 Yes, if you implement it correctly. Conceptually if you check all the steps 1 to 5 you can implement them with a single traversal over the list each, so they all take O(n) unless you do silly stuff in the implementation.

Comment: Can you please show me how it can be solved using Haskell?

Answer (score 3):

In the guards, `p x` and `otherwise` part both has problems.

`(p x) = 1 + (longestSequence p xs)` is not always true, if the next element of x does not hold predict `p`, it can not be added 1

`otherwise = longestSequence p xs` is not true if the current longest sequence is longer than the remained one

A possible fix is to maintain the max length and the current length

```
longestSequence :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
longestSequence p x = ls x 0 0
  where
    ls [] mx cur = max mx cur
    ls (x:xs) mx cur
        | p x = ls xs mx (cur+1)
        | otherwise = ls xs (max mx cur) 0
```

Comment: @Oni1 really sorry, copy&paste error, fixed in the otherwise part

Answer (score 2):

You can often use `fold` which is simpler than recursion, and in this case, we want to use [scanl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl), which is just like `foldl`, except it keeps the entire list.

The following iterates through the list, incrementing the count for every item that matches the predicate.  If it finds one that doesn't match, it resets the count back to zero.  At the end, it finds the maximum of the resulting list.

```
longestSequence p = maximum . scanl (\count x -> if (p x) then count + 1 else 0) 0
```

For your example input of `[1,44,33,22,2,3,55,66,66,77,88,99]` and predicate of `(\x -> x >= 10)`, the `scanl` will produce an output of `[0,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`.  Taking the maximum of this list gives `6`, and you can see that the maximum occurs at the end of the input, and also the zeroes in the list where the predicate didn't match.

Incidentally, I wholeheartedly agree with jpath about breaking down the problem into small parts.  I've seen people solve similar problems with a `fold` by cramming the `max` calculation inside the `\count` parameter with a tuple, but that makes it much harder to read.  That's also what makes single-function recursive solutions like yours difficult to wrap your head around, by the way.  Too much to keep track of at once, so it's hard to see where and how to fit in the reset-to-zero part.